# Magento order showing "Suspected Fraud" status for paypal payment

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

I have added `paypal standard payment` option in my magento store. In my magento store base currency is INR. But order status showing "Suspected Fraud" after successfully payment transaction.

How to resolve it?